# How to Download ExcelDownload in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

How to Download ExcelDownload in Django

my modules.py

```
**modules.py**
def getAnswerStats(year, month):
    answer_stats = Lawyer.objects.raw(''' select
        select * from (
            select 
                y.lawyer_name,
                DATE_FORMAT(y.register_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as reg_date,
                (select count(counsel_answer_idx) from counsel_answer where lawyer_idx = y.lawyer_idx and DATE_FORMAT(register_date, '%Y%m') = '%s') as cnt,
                (select count(counsel_answer_idx) from counsel_answer where lawyer_idx = y.lawyer_idx and DATE_FORMAT(register_date, '%Y%m') = '%s' and week(register_date,5) - week(DATE_SUB(register_date,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(register_date)-1 DAY),5) = 1) as cnt1
        where y.lawyer_status = 'N'
        ) A order by A.cnt desc ''', (year+month, year+month, year+month, year+month, year+month, year+month, year+month))

    return answer_stats
```

admin_view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def answer_stats_excel(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        year = request.POST.get("year")
        month = request.POST.get("month")
        print(year+month)

        stats_data = getAnswerStats(year, month)

    return redirect('/admin/visual/answer_stats')
```

The stats_data is retrieved from the module.

```
answer_stats.html

    <form id="boardFrm" name="boardFrm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/visual/answer_stats_excel" method="post">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <select class="form-control " style="width:49%" id="year" name="year"></select>
            <select class="form-control " style="width:49%" id="month" name="month"></select>
        </div>
            <button type="submit" style="margin-top:20px;" name="button"> excel down</button>
        </form>
```

ExcelDownload button here
How do I download the Exceldown button when I click it?

Comment: Your question is how to click btn `excel down` calling `def answer_stats_excel` or how to export excel file after click `excel down`?

Comment: If I click down, I want to make Excel download.

Comment: if you want excel download, you must create Excel file and return it, one can help you is pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/. Or you can see one simple example for me in this https://github.com/idontgotit/mysite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python  a simple module which works really good.You can use this for any type of files

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html